# Ruby Time doesn't keep offset when parsed

Tags: ruby, time, timezone

```
puts "date --- #{date}"
@date = Time.parse(date.to_s).iso8601 unless date.nil?
puts "@date -- #{@date}"
```

Outputs

```
Date --- 2012-08-12T12:15:17-07:00
@Date -- 2012-08-12T19:15:17+00:00
```

Anyone know why?

Additionally, this happens with strptime

```
Time.strptime("2012-08-12T12:05:08-07:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z")
=> 2012-08-12 19:05:08 +0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your system is set to UTC.  `Time.parse()` creates a new Time object, which uses the system timezone, and sets it to the time that is parsed.  It doesn't change the timezone of the new Time to match the timezone of the parsed date.  If you really want that behavior, you can use something like:

```
DateTime.parse(date.to_s).new_offset(date.iso8601[-6,6]).iso8601
```

**Update:** Regarding the `strptime()` part of the question that was just added, it's the exact same concept.  A new Time is being created with the default timezone, with a time that matches the date that you're parsing.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a more robust way of doing this other than trying to parse the string to get the offset. Assume that 'date' being passed in is a string most of the time.

Comment: @aciniglio I don't believe so.  If you can ensure that the string `date` is always in one particular format or another (like iso8601), then just grabbing the last 6 characters (or 5 for some other formats) should be fine. Otherwise you'll want to write something a little more elaborate to make sure you always grab the right thing.  If you have an actual Time object, the `zone()` method would be best.